# Some, but not all, long-running 3rd party apps (e.g., Matlab & Cygwin processes) seem to terminate mysteriously

Tags: windows-10

I'm executing many-day Matlab jobs on Windows 10.  On two successive occassions, when the job has run for about a day, I found that the Matlab process and my Cygwin Xterm and Gvim processes are gone.  Firefox and Outlook 2013 are still running.

I look at the Matlab log file (i.e., its "diary") and found typical output, suddenly end in the middle of a text line, indicating a highly abnormal interruption.  The abruptness of the interruption is reinforced by the fact that my Matlab code creates an "onCleanup" object that flushes buffered output to the diary when it is destroyed, and it is clear that the object didn't even get a chance to be destroyed.

Since the Cygwin X-Windows is also no longer running, the problem does not look like it is specific to Matlab.  The Cygwin processes are unrelated to the Matlab process, i.e., Matlab is not an X-windows process, and was not launched from Bash.

#### How can I begin to track down what caused these terminations?

---

#### The smoking gun: A Windows update and restart

As per [user1686's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1717126/some-but-not-all-long-running-3rd-party-apps-seem-to-terminate-mysteriously#comment2649343_1717126), I ran the Event Viewer.  The top level container is "Event Viewer (Local).  Therein is a "Windows Logs" container, which contains containers "Application" and "System". Nothing suspicious in "Application", but the "System" container contained the following incriminating event:

```
Level: Information
Date and Time: 2022-04-16 12:25:01 AM
Source: User32
Event ID: 1074
Task Category: None
```

In the viewing pain, the "General" tab contained:

```
The process C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe (*computer name*) has initiated the restart of computer *computer name* on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: Operating System: Service pack (Planned)

Log Name: System
Source: User32
Event ID: 1074
Level: Information
User: SYSTEM
OpCode: Info
More Information: Event Log Online Help (this is a hyperlink)
Logged: 2022-04-16 12:25:01 AM
Task Category: None
Keywords: Classic
Computer: *Computer name*
```

The smoking gun is the time stamp of 12:25:01 AM.  This coincides with the time stamp of a file that Matlab updates every 30 seconds or so. Specifically, `ls -l` shows the time stamp `Apr 16 00:25` (I can't play with `ls` to get a more precise time because I restarted the Matlab job, which clobbered the file).

It is impossible for me to fully express how appalled I am that the default behaviour is for a restart to occur without user confirmation. My next step is to prevent this. Any leads would be welcome. I considered starting a new question, but this still seems to fall under the title of this question.  Thanks.

P.S. I find it bizarre that Firefox and Outlook are still running. Perhaps Windows tries to clobber any processes in preparation to restart, but is unable to clobber Firefox and Outlook.

Comment: Was Matlab itself running as an X client? Have you checked the two main logs in `eventvwr.msc` (System and Application) for crash reports?

Comment: @user1686: No, the Matlab is a Windows version and uses the Windows windowing system. I only use Cygwin for xterm, bash, and Gvim. These are completely separate from Matlab. I ran the Event Viewer as you suggested and added the very revealing information that it provided. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> P.S. I find it bizarre that Firefox and Outlook are still running. Perhaps Windows tries to clobber any processes in preparation to restart, but is unable to clobber Firefox and Outlook.

An OS reboot necessarily kills *all* processes, without exception – but what really happens is that Firefox and Outlook register themselves to be *automatically re-started* after Windows reboot (similar to the XSMP "session save" mechanism previously seen in Linux X11 environments), while other apps don't do that.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I'm slogging through Group Policy Editor pages to make the reboot less lethal. When logged in as non-administrator, I can usually search for apps from the Windows Start button, then right-click or Ctrl+right-click or Shift+Ctrl+right-click to run as administrator. Gpedit doesn't seem to behave that way. I can get around that by running `cmd` as administrator and entering `gpedit.msc`. The next sleuthing exercise is to find "Configure Automatic Updates", as required by [this procedure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-restart).

Comment: I would suggest first just enabling the Windows Update option to [notify early when a reboot is needed](https://i.imgur.com/rGdNP1S.png) (not via GPO, just in the Settings app under "Advanced"). With this option you can _plan_ for reboots – without it, Windows might sit silently on a pending reboot for several days until suddenly forcing one. Fully preventing reboots, however, is a fight for *another* thread (and I think you may need Enterprise) and I'm not sure if needed. My own Win10 desktop typically has uptime in months, with only an occasional critical security update requesting a reboot.

Comment: Thank you again, user1686. That's a much better option. The options under [Configure Automatic Updates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-restart) in gpedit.msc are all bad. None of them allow for a user to postpone a reboot to for an arbitrary duration, or for an aribtrary number of times.

Comment: I could go on a well justified rant (like [here](https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/316460-how-to-stop-forced-windows-reboots) and [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disable-windows-10-automatic-restart-after-updates/16f1826d-a796-4de8-ac99-1d625420d265?auth=1)) and threaten to abandon Windows, but I am trapped by dependence on apps supported only on Windows.

Comment: Well, I got a notification that a restart will occur outside of working hours, which is 8am to 5pm. It hasn't clobbered my job yet, even though it is outside of office hours. I went to Settings -> Windows Update -> Advanced options. The resulting panel provided controls to pause updates for as long as May 7. I chose April 28. It's ambiguous what this means, however, as the update is already commenced, and needs a reboot to complete. Hopefully, this means that the reboot is staved off until April 28.